# How to get rid of the NaN/NaN/NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the table, for the skips day column, the last row's default value will always be the word "last" which isn't a number. Now, the result date show "NaN/NaN/NaN",is there any way that i can replace that with sth like Nil.

Many thanks.

```js
   $('input.date, input.day').on('change', function () {
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var start = $row.find('.date').val();
 if (start) {
   var set = new Date(start);
   set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));
   $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
   var dt = set.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (set.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + set.getDate()).slice(-2);
   $row.next('tr').find('.date').attr('value', dt).trigger('change');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="10" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="15" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="last" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not change your `day` inputs from `text` to `number`? It makes sense since you will only want a number input. This will also remove the `NAN`

Comment: the thing is for the last row of the skip day, the default value will be last, it's not a number

Comment: Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/1ayn5tng/ Not sure why you would have the default value of last so maybe my example isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input.date, input.day').on('change', function () {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var start = $row.find('.date').val();
 
  if (!isNaN($row.find(".day").val()) && start) {
    var set = new Date(start);
    set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));
    $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
    var dt = set.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (set.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + set.getDate()).slice(-2);
    $row.next('tr').find('.date').attr('value', dt).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="10" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="15" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="last" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I've used `iSNaN` to check the `input.day` value

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @tam Welcome buddy :)

Comment: oh and one small issue, when i try to change to skip day to one, the start date is the same as the result date, any idea?, thanks

Comment: i fix it, timezone issue

Comment: @tam That's awesome. I was unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just manually update the last cell to overwrite the `Null`value with something like: `$("#one tbody tr:last-of-type .result")[0].value = 'Nil'`.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
$('input.date, input.day').on('change', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var start = $row.find('.date').val();
  if (start) {
    var set = new Date(start);
    set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));
    $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(),
      set.getFullYear()
    ].join('/'));
    var dt = set.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (set.getMonth() +
      1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + set.getDate()).slice(-2);
    $row.next('tr').find('.date').attr('value', dt).trigger('change');
  }
  $("#one tbody tr:last-of-type .result")[0].value = 'Nil';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="10" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="15" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="last" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)